# -bash: ./a.out: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error in VSCode

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio-code

I am trying to do ./a.out > outfile to see if my code is working the way it is supposed to. But I keep getting this error whenever I run gcc -m32 p1.c (my class requires we run -m32 for compilation)

Comment: @IrAM I use VSCode in Linux, you may be confusing it with Visual Studio. VSCode on Linux has a built-in bash terminal that I use for compiling files.

Comment: what does the command `file a.out` say?